# Node.toprettyxml() adds newlines to DOCTYPE in Python

Tags: python, xml, pretty-print, elementtree, minidom

When using `prettify` my DOCTYPE is broken into three lines. How can I keep it on one line?

The "broken" output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE smil
  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN'
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd'>
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_256.mp4" system-bitrate="336000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_512.mp4" system-bitrate="592000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_768.mp4" system-bitrate="848000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_1128.mp4" system-bitrate="1208000"/>
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

The script:

```python
import csv
import sys
import os.path

from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(doctype, elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = doctype + ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ", encoding = 'utf-8')

doctype = '<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">'

video_data = ((256, 336000),
              (512, 592000),
              (768, 848000),
              (1128, 1208000))


with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        root = Element('smil')
        root.set('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language')
        head = SubElement(root, 'head')
        meta = SubElement(head, 'meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand"')
        body = SubElement(root, 'body')

        switch_tag = ElementTree.SubElement(body, 'switch')

        for suffix, bitrate in video_data:
            attrs = {'src': ("mp4:soundcheck/{year}/{id}/{file_root_name}_{suffix}.mp4"
                             .format(suffix=str(suffix), **row)),
                     'system-bitrate': str(bitrate),
                     }
            ElementTree.SubElement(switch_tag, 'video', attrs)

        file_root_name = row["file_root_name"]
        year = row["year"]
        id = row["id"]
        path = year+'-'+id

        file_name = row['file_root_name']+'.smil'
        full_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
        output = open(full_path, 'w')
        output.write(prettify(doctype, root))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked over your current script and the other questions you've asked on this subject, I think you could make your life a lot simpler by building your smil files using string manipulation.

Almost all the xml in your files is static. The only data you need to worry about processing correctly is the attribute values for the `video` tag. And for that, there is a handy function in the standard library that does exactly what you want: [xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr).

So, with those points in mind, here is a script that should be a lot easier to work with:

```
import sys, os, csv
from xml.sax.saxutils import quoteattr

smil_header = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
'''
smil_video = '''\
      <video src=%s system-bitrate=%s/>
'''
smil_footer = '''\
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
'''

src_format = 'mp4:soundcheck/%(year)s/%(id)s/%(file_root_name)s_%(suffix)s.mp4'

video_data = (
    ('256', '336000'), ('512', '592000'),
    ('768', '848000'), ('1128', '1208000'),
    )

root = os.getcwd()
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    root = sys.argv[2]

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as stream:

    for row in csv.DictReader(stream):
        smil = [smil_header]
        for suffix, bitrate in video_data:
            row['suffix'] = suffix
            smil.append(smil_video % (
                quoteattr(src_format) % row, quoteattr(bitrate)
                ))
        smil.append(smil_footer)

        directory = os.path.join(root, '%(year)s-%(id)s' % row)
        try:
            os.makedirs(directory)
        except OSError:
            pass
        path = os.path.join(directory, '%(file_root_name)s.smil' % row)
        print ':: writing file:', path
        with open(path, 'wb') as stream:
            stream.write(''.join(smil))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have at least three options:

1. Just accept the newlines. They may be undesired and ugly but they are perfectly legal.
2. Add a kludge that replaces the bad DOCTYPE with a nicer one. Perhaps something like this:

   ```python
   import re

   pretty_xml = prettify(doctype, elem)
   m = re.search("(<!.*dtd'>)", pretty_xml, re.DOTALL)
   ugly_doctype = m.group() 
   fixed_xml = pretty_xml.replace(ugly_doctype, doctype)
   ```
3. Use a more feature-rich XML package. [lxml](http://lxml.de) springs to mind; it is mostly compatible with ElementTree. By using lxml's [`tostring`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring) function, you won't need the `prettify` function and the DOCTYPE comes out as you want it. Example:

   ```python
   from lxml import etree 

   doctype = '<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">'

   XML = '<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language"><head><meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand"/></head><body><switch><video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_256.mp4" system-bitrate="336000"/><video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_512.mp4" system-bitrate="592000"/><video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_768.mp4" system-bitrate="848000"/><video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_1128.mp4" system-bitrate="1208000"/></switch></body></smil>'

   elem = etree.fromstring(XML)
   print etree.tostring(elem, doctype=doctype, pretty_print=True,
                        xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">
   <smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
     <head>
       <meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand"/>
     </head>
     <body>
       <switch>
         <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_256.mp4" system-bitrate="336000"/>
         <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_512.mp4" system-bitrate="592000"/>
         <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_768.mp4" system-bitrate="848000"/>
         <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_1128.mp4" system-bitrate="1208000"/>
       </switch>
     </body>
   </smil>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to remove the newlines generated by `Node.toprettyxml` for the `DOCTYPE`, at least in a Pythonic way.

It's the `writexml` method of the `DocumentType` class, which starts at line 1284 of the [`minidom` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/dom/minidom.py), which inserts the offending newlines.  The newline string inserted comes originally from the `Node.toprettyxml` method and is passed via the `writexml` method of the `Document` class.  The same newline string is also passed to the `writexml` method of various other subclasses of `Node`.  Changing the newline string in the call to `Node.prettyxml` will change the newline string used throughout the outputted XML.

There are various hacky ways around this: modify your local copy of the `minidom` module, 'monkey-patch' the `writexml` method of the `DocumentType` class or post-process the XML string to remove the unwanted newlines.  However, none of these approaches appeal to me.

To me, the best approach seems to be to leave things as they are.  Is it really a serious problem having the `DOCTYPE` split over multiple lines?