# Remove XML Version Tag from ElementTree using Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've needed to manually add my xml version as a string so I need to remove the xml version generated by ElementTree. How do I remove the duplicate xml version node on line 3?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_256.mp4" system-bitrate="336000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_512.mp4" system-bitrate="592000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_768.mp4" system-bitrate="848000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_1128.mp4" system-bitrate="1208000"/>
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

This is the script;

```
def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ", encoding = 'utf-8')

xmlver = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n'
doctype = '<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">\n'

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        root = Element('smil')
        root.set('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language')
        head = SubElement(root, 'head')
        meta = SubElement(head, 'meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand"')
        body = SubElement(root, 'body')

        switch_tag = ElementTree.SubElement(body, 'switch')

        for suffix, bitrate in video_data:
            attrs = {'src': ("mp4:soundcheck/{year}/{id}/{file_root_name}_{suffix}.mp4"
                             .format(suffix=str(suffix), **row)),
                     'system-bitrate': str(bitrate),
                     }
            ElementTree.SubElement(switch_tag, 'video', attrs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the xml processing instruction generated by `ElemenTtree`, and insert a doctype node into the `minidom` document:

```
def prettify(elem, doctype=None):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    if doctype is not None:
        reparsed.insertBefore(doctype, reparsed.documentElement)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ", encoding = 'utf-8')

doctype = minidom.getDOMImplementation('').createDocumentType(
    'smil', '-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN',
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd')
```

Comment: Although this answer solves the immediate problem, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8690365/984421) to your other question on this subject for a more complete solution.